Cholesky factorization in L-BFGS-B
L-BFGS-B is one of the most used quasi-Newton solver and the original paper [1] is quite explicit about how to implement the algorithm. In one of the following paper [2], they detail the reference Fortran implementation (alg. 778) that was last updated in 2011 [3] and available here: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/279232.279236
There is however, one equality that I don't understand. In [2], they claim that the following equality holds
$$
\left(\mathbf{I} - \dfrac{1}{\theta} \mathbf{MW}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{ZZ}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{W}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} -\mathbf{D} - \dfrac{1}{\theta} \mathbf{Y}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{ZZ}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{L}_A^{\mathrm{T}} - \mathbf{R}_Z^{\mathrm{T}} \\ \mathbf{L}_A - \mathbf{R}_Z & \theta \mathbf{S}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{AA}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{S}\end{bmatrix}^{-1},
$$
where $\mathbf{L}_A$ is the strict lower triangle of $\mathbf{S}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{AA}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{R}_Z$ is the upper triangle of $\mathbf{Y}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{ZZ}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{Y}$.
Does anyone knows how to derive it ? I checked in all refrences about Limited BFGS matrices representation refrences [1-4] and found nothing...
Note that the goal of this equality is to obtain a factorization applying cholesky to the four blocks of the matrix. Then inversion is easy.
Thank you in advance for your help.
References
[1] Richard H. Byrd, Peihuang Lu, Jorge Nocedal, and Ciyou Zhu. A Limited Memory Algorithm for Bound Constrained Optimization. SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing, 16(5):1190–1208, September 1995. doi:10.1137/0916069.
[2] Ciyou Zhu, Richard H. Byrd, Peihuang Lu, and Jorge Nocedal. Algorithm 778: L-BFGS-B: Fortran subroutines for large-scale bound-constrained optimization. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 23(4):550–560, December 1997. doi:10.1145/279232.279236.
[3] José Luis Morales and Jorge Nocedal. Remark on “algorithm 778: L-BFGS-B: Fortran subroutines for large-scale bound constrained optimization”. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 38(1):7:1–7:4, December 2011. doi:10.1145/2049662.2049669.
[4] Richard H. Byrd, Jorge Nocedal, and Robert B. Schnabel. Representations of quasi-Newton matrices and their use in limited memory methods. Mathematical Programming, 63(1-3):129–156, 1994. doi:10.1007/BF01582063.

Please, provide more notation. What is $\mathbf{D}$, $\mathbf{M}$, $\mathbf{Z}$ and what are their sizes...?
